# DatePicker strange validation

Tags: c#, wpf, datetime, datepicker

I have a DatePicker with is defined through the follwing XAML:

```
<DatePicker Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Margin="4" 
    Text="{Binding Birthday, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
    DisplayDateStart="01.01.1900" DisplayDateEnd="{Binding CurrentDate, Mode=OneTime}"/>
```

If I select a Date like '02.03.1979' everything is fine. But if I select '27.12.1979' the Field of the DatePicker gets a red border. I have no validation for this date.

Why are some dates are red?

Birthday is a property of Type Datetime. Currendate is a property of type DateTime which return the actual date.

Comment: Most likely your date configuration is set to use a US format of MM/DD/YYYY so 27/12 is an invalid date. Can't help you further out of the top of my head though, sorry.

Comment: So how can I set the format to German format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by binding to the DisplayDate instead of Text. The code now looks like:

```
<DatePicker Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Margin="4" 
DisplayDate="{Binding Birthday, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
DisplayDateStart="01.01.1900" DisplayDateEnd="{Binding CurrentDate, Mode=OneTime}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your xaml code is ok. If you want to use the same DateTime format for multiple DatePicker, add this code-snippet to your startup window - you may edit the pattern:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = (CultureInfo)Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Clone();
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "dd. MMM. yyyy";
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are not particular about the order of your date values.. try this

```
<DatePicker Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Margin="4" 
    Text="{Binding Birthday, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
    DisplayDateStart="01.01.1900" DisplayDateEnd="{Binding CurrentDate, Mode=OneTime}" Format="Custom" FormatString="MMM dd yyyy"/>
```

Comment: I don't have to Properties Format and FormatString on the DatePicker

Comment: oh nevermind, I got it confused with the Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.DateTimePicker